# Store local data in java?

Tags: java, text, storage

I am using Java to make a simple text adventure. I want to be able to define progress each mission, and that will store somewhere in the user's appdata to be read next time they play the game. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?  Are you trying to figure out what APIs let you do this, or are you concerned about security issues with saving across a connection?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions on SO tend to be pretty concrete questions which involve a little bit of code. Your question is pretty vague; it might get voted down or even closed. Could you make it more specific? Maybe include some code you've already tried?

Comment: I don't imagine your game has much data to store. The whole idea of storage is to make a file, put some stuff in to represent where you are, save it on the harddrive, then retrieve it when needed. The first thing you want to do is to decide exactly what you need to store to get the result you want. If it's a little bit of information, a little text file will do the trick. If it's a lot, then maybe you'll want to use a database. The answers below offer some fine storage techniques, but I want to see some code before I'd recommend anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store the data internally (i.e., save across sessions, but not as a user-readable file), I would use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html).

For example: consider that you have a class called `MissionInfo` which implements `java.io.Serializable`. You could do the following:

```
// Precondition: missionInfoToSave is an variable of type MissionInfo

// The key used to store the data.
final String key = "SAVE_DATA";

// Get the preferences database for this package.
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MissionInfo.class);

// To save, write the object to a byte array.
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(missionInfoToSave); // write it to the stream
    prefs.putByteArray(key, baos.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException ie) {
    System.err.println("Failed to save to file");
}

// To load, read it back.
// The second argument is the default if the key isn't found.
byte[] stored = prefs.getByteArray(key, null);
if (stored == null) {
    // There's no stored data.
    return;
}
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream();
try {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    Object o = ois.readObject();
    if (o instanceof MissionData) { 
        // Good: it's a saved data file.
        updateMissionProgress((MissionData) o); // assuming this is defined
    }
} catch (IOException ie) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't load from prefs");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    System.err.println("Class couldn't be found");
}
```

The Preferences API will store the data across sessions. You can find it in the package [`java.util.prefs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html).

Comment: I was marshalling to XMLs but I was not having much luck. I haven't tried much else because I am a novice Java coder.

Comment: If you understand how to write to XML, what is your question? XML should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), which is a convenient utility for creating a map of keys and values, storing it in a file, and loading a related `Properties` object from that file.  A nice tutorial on using Java's `Properties` with files can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

To get the AppData directory file path (in Windows), you can utilize `System.getenv("APPDATA")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple database: sqlite or Berkeley DB
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/index.html

Comment: Or Derby, the relational database that ships with the JDK.

Comment: This would require that the database software is installed on each user's operating system.  Even assuming users have JDK is a stretch, as most simply have JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a application specific folder located in the user home directory which you can get with this code:

```
String userHome=System.getProperty("user.home");
```

That will give you a string to something like c:\Documents and Settings\user1 and then you can append to that string your appname like "adventureapp" with a forwardd slash first. Then from that. You can do this :

```
File file = new File(mypathtomyappfolder);
```

Then you test if .isDirectory() if not, it is the first time user is running app do file.newDir() so you have your adventureapp directory. Then from there use File and append a file name to your string like user.properties which you can read and write to based on their progression in the game. Hope that helps. - Duncan