# What are the possible ways to implement a payment subscription model?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a subscription model for my app which charges from user's credit/debit card every month (**recurring payment**). I would like to know if there is a standard set of steps I must follow to achieve this? If not what are the possible ways I could use to do this?

For an example, If I save subscription start date and end date in the database what can I do to detect each user's end date on time and perform the monthly transaction via payment gateway?

(I know I have to use a payment gateway on one step to handle transactions for that I'm planning to use an existing product.)

Can someone please guide me on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, First Locally second store end date on server.

**Locally:** If you just want to store the data internally, You can use the [Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html). You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484549/store-local-data-in-java).

**Server:** Store the start and end date in users table and when user enter the application you can retrieve the values and check if the subscription is expired.